# Process of finding sum of cells from multiple sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I've roughly 100 text files that I imported to Excel (using 2010).  Each sheet has a value in column I that I need to total; the row of the value varies, though it is the final row in all cases.

Since I couldn't think of a decent way to code a way to sum those values without essentially "copying" the data, I think I've a process I want to go and need corrected/helped if this is incorrect.

I want to find the last row in column I (my range) and place this on a new sheet, creating a list; this will be in column B on the new page.  Column A must state the title of the sheet the data was pulled from.

I will sum the value at this point.

So far, I've nothing.  I tried coding the following which appears to give me zilch:

```
Sub Scuba()

Dim ws As worksheet
Dim rng As Object
Dim numrows As Integer

numrows = Rows.Count
Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 9), .Cells(numrows, 9))

worksheet.Add.Name = Tally

For Each ws In Workbook

Sheets("Tally").Range(xlEnd.Row + 1, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
Sheets("Tally").Range(xlEnd.Row + 1, 2).Value = rng.xlEnd

Next

End Sub
```

All of the data is formatted as such:

```
20141103-20141107

Date  In    Out   Listing
1103  0710  1710  1000 - 1000
1104  0715  1800  1045 - 2045
1105  0715  1800  1045 - 3130
1106  0700  1745  1045 - 4215
1107  0700  1015  0315 - 4530
```

The delineated indicates new cells on spaces.  The value I want to keep and total would would be the final listing of 4530, in this example.

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Edit:

As I'm having issues choosing the last cell in a column, maybe I can just get the last row from each sheet onto a new sheet, in a list fashion.  This would at least make it easier to manage for the overall project (# of text files varies per person as it's how much work they've put into the time recording program; I'll be doing this for multiple persons to attribute hours worked in X duration).
I would still like to have the sheet which it's taken from in Column A, starting the copied last row in Column B.

I'll post more as this progresses.  Thanks for all of the input so far.

Comment: Do you have a sum for column I on each sheet currently?  Or do you want the macro to create a sum for each sheet?  My answer below assumes you DO NOT have a sum on each sheet.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on that; the collection of text files is someone pooling their hours and showing total in the week, so it is a sum of values in the row.  The tally, when deliniated in excel, shows up in column I.

Comment: Could you provide an example screenshot (with confidential data withheld) for us to look at?

Comment: Just added an example of the data.  Those are how each text file is laid out.  If additional time is used on a date, it is listed below the date, with a blank space where the date should be.

Comment: Have you tried running my second answer (after the edit) code?

Comment: I missed that you edited it; I'll give it a shot.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will create a new sheet "Tally" (unless it already exists) and add lines with each worksheet's name and final hours.  I have tested the below successfully.

Edit:  THIS CODE IS TESTED WORKING

```
   Sub Scuba()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim RunSub As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim NameTest As String
    Dim NewWS As Worksheet

    On Error Resume Next

    'Creates Tally sheet if it doesn't exist
    NameTest = Worksheets("Tally").Name
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Else
        Err.Clear
        Set NewWS = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(Before:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1))
            NewWS.Name = "Tally"
    End If

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not ws.Name = "Tally" Then
            LastRow = ws.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            DestRow = Sheets("Tally").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Sheets("Tally").Range("A" & DestRow).Value = ws.Name
            Sheets("Tally").Range("B" & DestRow).Value = ws.Range("I" & LastRow).Value
        Else
        End If
    Next ws

    DestRow = Sheets("Tally").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheets("Tally").Range("A" & DestRow).Value = "Grand Total"
    Sheets("Tally").Range("B" & DestRow).Value = Application.Sum(Range("B1:B" & DestRow - 1))

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Just tried the second set of code (post-edit) and it appears to add the column up + an additional last row.  This does not appear to be what I'm looking for as, in terms of hours worked, column I is itself a sum, with the last row being the total worked for that week.  Thanks for input!

Comment: Got an email about this one, took a look at it, and I'm unsure how this is happening... column I lists: 0, 0805, 1610, 2045, 2600, 3200 (end of week, person worked 32 hours).  You code sums the column, but the sum in the messagebox for this says "159415."

Comment: Tomorrow, I'm going to take a minute and figure out why my loop isn't working with the above code ("for each worksheet in workbook" should not be giving me an object error).  I'll play around a bit more with you code, but thank you for the input thusfar!  If nothing else, it's helping me with how to appropriately list the function.

Comment: My code sums each last value in "I" for each worksheet.  How many worksheets are in your book? is 1594.15 hours a reasonable sum of all hours worked for 100 sheets?

Comment: If my code is outputing 159415 then that should be the sum of all (total/final) hours worked across all 100 sheets. (Which I believe is what you originally asked for).

Comment: I should by more specific, sorry: It changes on every sheet.  The 159415 shows up on one page, while on another, it shows 2400 (on the page showing 2400, the hours worked were 1610 [0810, 0800]).

Comment: What is the total hours worked for the week across all workers (as in the answer you are trying to get)?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are saying that for each different sheet you run this on, it gives you a different number in the message box?  Or is the message box always say 159415?

Comment: On each page, I am getting different values in the messagebox (I tested several pages, not all, and had different values on each).  The hours worked in a week are totaled and displayed as the last line in the final column; I want to sum those values across all sheets.  My preference is to copy the value and make a list on a separate sheet (tally) so we can attribute workloads on the date the value represents.

Comment: Completely new method for you to try.

Comment: Wunderbar!  Thank you so much for sticking with me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps.

```
Sub Scuba()

  Dim ws As Worksheet, wsTally As Worksheet
  Dim rng As Object
  Dim numrows As Integer

  Set wsTally = Worksheets.Add

  'if there is already a sheet named Tally, then this will result in wsTally being called Sheet6 or whatever...
  On Error Resume Next
  wsTally.Name = "Tally"
  On Error GoTo 0

  Dim i As Long
  i = 1

  With wsTally
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook
      i = i + 1
      .Range(i + 1, 1).value = ws.Name
      .Range(i + 1, 2).value = LastValInRow(9, ws).value
    Next ws
  End With

End Sub

Function LastValInRow(Column As Long, WrkSht As Worksheet) As Range
  Dim c As Range
  Set c = WrkSht.Columns(Column)

  'get the last cell excel thinks is uesd
  Dim LstUsed As Long
  LstUsed = c.Rows.Count + 1
  'add one, just in case excel is correct

  'get the actual last used cell
  Dim r As Range
  ' .End(xlUp) is equivalent to Ctrl+Up
  Set r = c.Cells(LstUsed, 1).End(xlUp)

  Set LastValInRow = r
End Function
```

Comment: I tried this code and received a run-time error '438': Object does not support this property or method.  This appears on "For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook."  Trying to figure out why Excel is hating that today.

Comment: Not sure why this fixed it, but I retyped ActiveWorkbook and it worked; I'm now getting an automation error ['-2147221080 (800401a8)] on ".Range(i + 1, 1).Value =".  Trying to read up about it.